# Hardware clock and date not aligned

Tags: linux-kernel, clock

On a Linux device I am using the `hwclock` command and the `date` command return different values:

```
root@myhost:/home/user# hwclock
2021-04-08 15:12:55.878171+02:00
root@myhost:/home/user# date
Thu  8 Apr 15:09:03 CEST 2021
```

I am facing this issue when I boot the device *without* an Internet connection.

Info about the system:

```
root@myhost:/home/user# uname -a
Linux myhost 4.19.75-v7l+ #14 SMP Wed Apr 1 10:28:32 CEST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```